# Add button to jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I can not add button to this jquery ui dialog.
if possible please give me an example .
thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //setup new person dialog
        $('#dialog2').dialog({
            autoResize: true,
            show: "clip",
            hide: "clip",
            height: 'auto',
            width: '1000',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: 'top',
            draggable: false,
            title: "انتخاب درخواست",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });

        $('#viewfaktor').dialog({
            autoResize: true,
            show: "clip",
            hide: "clip",
            height: 'auto',
            width: '1000',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: 'top',
            draggable: true,
            title: "مشاهده صورت ریز",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });


        $('#msgBox').dialog({


            autoResize: true,
            show: "clip",
            hide: "clip",
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: 'center',
            draggable: false,



            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }


        });



    });

    function showDialog(id) {
        $('#' + id).dialog("open");
    }

    function closeDialog(id) {
        $('#' + id).dialog("destroy");
    }



</script>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('#msgBox').dialog({
    autoResize: true,
    show: "clip",
    hide: "clip",
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    draggable: false,

    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    },

    buttons: { "OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } 
});
```

Answer (score 32):

Sometimes you want to add the buttons dynamically after the dialog is created too. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304825/#7436350) at the question  [Add a button to a dialog box dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304825)

```
var mydialog = ... result of jqueryui .dialog()
var buttons = mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons"); // getter
$.extend(buttons, { foo: function () { alert('foo'); } });
mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons); // setter
```

Comment: How would you add a button with a specific ID?

Comment: why would you need an id on the button?

Comment: or do you mean add an existing button identified by an ID?

Comment: @JSS: Could you provide an example of how to change the order in which the buttons appear on the modal?

Comment: @KSwift87 - ask a new SO question, and include the code you are already using.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to add a button to a dialog that is already open you can do something like:

```
var buttonSet = $('#dialog').parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonset');
var newButton = $('<button>My New Button</button>');
newButton.button().click(function () {
    alert('My new button clicked');
});
buttonSet.append(newButton);
```

Answer (score 8):

[Here is an example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)

add this to your function:

```
buttons: {
                OK: function() { //submit
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() { //cancel
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
```

So you get

```
    $('#msgBox').dialog({


                autoResize: true,
                show: "clip",
                hide: "clip",
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                position: 'center',
                draggable: false,
                buttons: {
                OK: function() { //ok
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() { //cancel
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }


            });
```