# Add a button to a dialog box dynamically

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Is there any way to add a button to a dialog box in jquery ui dynamically.

I tried using: $(this).add("button");

Comment: Welcome to SO!... Kut please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq and accept answers that assisted you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? If you want to enable certain actions based on changes in the dialogue box, you should be enabling/disabling existing buttons, not appending new ones.

Comment: @aditya: i even thought that.. so, is there ny way to change the value of a button dynamically...

Comment: Depending on how you're adding buttons, you can change the value of a button. If you're using @charliegriefer's way (which is the correct way), the only way I could come up with is using `$(".ui-dialog").find('button')` to find all the buttons, then changing the value for the one you're looking for. If you're adding buttons by specifying them in the HTML itself, then use `$("#dialog").find('button')`. All this is after you've called `.dialog()` on your selector, of course. This is *not* a good way to do it however, so proceed with caution.

Comment: @Kut Would you mind commenting why my upvoted answer has not been accepted as correct? Did the example not fulfill your requirement in some way?

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes you want to add the buttons later too.

```
var mydialog = ... result of jqueryui .dialog()
var buttons = mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons"); // getter
$.extend(buttons, { foo: function () { alert('foo'); } });
mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons); // setter
```

Comment: Clever.  However, this seems to overwrite any buttons that may have already been instantiated.  I thought the $.extend() would simply add the new buttons alongside any existing ones.

Comment: Yes, it does overwrite the buttons. That's why it's necessary to GET the collection of buttons, add a new one using EXTEND, and then re-applying the collection. http://jsfiddle.net/Z8pZt/

Comment: You can use "$.extend" if you want to change the properties of a button (i.e., change the text of the click function), but if you want to "add" a new button, you should use "$.merge" range than $.extend.  Otherwise, awesome.

Comment: @Michael thanks for mentioning the difference between $.merge and $extend. I didn't know $.merge existed. Buttons does accept either an object or an array. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons. I'm using the object variant where "the keys are the button labels and the values are the callbacks for when the associated button is clicked.". If I were adding multiple buttons, I can see where using an array with $.merge would be preferrable. Thanks for pointing out a potential issue with my example, and that it's different from the documentation.

Comment: this didn't work for me. :/ alternatively, what i did was finding modal-footer element which wraps the buttons section and appending button html code directly to it.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş can you post your code to jsfiddle? I'd be happy to suggest why it's wrong.

Comment: I realized that I wasn't using JqueryUI, instead, I am using Jquery with bootbox dialog, and that's why your solution didn't work for me. Thanks for following up. :)

Answer (score 10):

This is answered right on the jQuery UI page for dialog... http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ (click "Options" tab, then the link for "Buttons")

"Get or set the buttons option, after init"...

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", { 
 "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
} );
```

Just add the appropriate selector (whatever element you're using as the dialog), and you should be good to go.