# Adding Buttons to $.dialog (jquery-confirm.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm currently using jquery-confirm.js for alerts, confirms and dialogs.

https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

The problem is I can't adapt buttons to dialogs, I'm not sure if it's a plugin thing or is just my lack of knowledge about JS.

For example, I have this dialog:

```
                setTimeout(function () {
              $.dialog({
                title: 'Existing user',
                content: "This account is already registered on our system. If you are the real owner, contact us!",
                icon: 'fas fa-user',
                theme: 'modern',
                animation: 'scale',
                type: 'red',
                draggable: false,
                closeIcon: function () {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      window.location="/dashboard";
                  }, 250);
                }
              });
            }, 200);
```

The only button is closeIcon. How could I do if I want to addapt this to him? I mean, the `buttons`.

```
                        $.confirm({
                        title: 'Confirmation',
                        content: 'Are you sure do you want to delete <strong>'+ig_name+'</strong>? We will delete all the information, however you will be able to add it again whenever you want.',
                        icon: 'fa fa-user-times',
                        animation: 'scale',
                        closeAnimation: 'scale',
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        draggable: false,
                        escapeKey: 'cancel',
                        buttons: {
                            'confirm': {
                                text: 'Delete',
                                btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                                action: function () {
                                  document.getElementById('DeleteAccountForm1').submit();
                                } 
                            },
                            cancel: {
                              text : 'Cancel',
                            },
                        }
                    });
                });
```

**EDIT:**

I tried with this, but $.dialog is not being shown.

```
    buttons: {
    confirm: function () {
        $.alert('Confirmed!');
    },
    cancel: function () {
        $.alert('Canceled!');
    },
```

Comment: Whcih jQuery-confirm.js you are using? Can you share that site link?

Comment: @RohitMittal Added to the question! I'm sorry, I forgot it.

Comment: Can you add a codepen as your last code snippet seems fine and should work properly.

Comment: @RohitMittal Exactly, last code snippet is okay since it's about a $.confirm, the problem is trying to add those buttons into a $.dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add button to jquery ui dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031673/add-button-to-jquery-ui-dialog)

Comment: @RohitMittal I tried with that, but $.dialog is not being shown.